# Is there a way to listen system output volume mute event on Mac？

Tags: macos, core-audio

Just like the title, I want to know how to listen the system output volume changed event.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oH0e.png)

Comment: Audio devices have a property `kAudioDevicePropertyMute` that you should be able to observe for changes using a property listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener` to add a `kAudioDevicePropertyMute` property listener exactly solved this problem.